# How to prevent meteor from rerendering a template?

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, meteor

I'm trying to work around a [reported bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161004&can=1&q=tlau%40willowgarage.com&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) in Chrome that causes <img> tags that reference long-running video streams to consume server connections even after they are deleted from the DOM.

I have an <img> tag in my Meteor app which points to a reactive variable for its src URL. This lives inside a template which contains many other reactive variables.

The problem is that whenever any of those other variables changes, Meteor will re-render the entire template, including my image tag. Even though the image tag gets deleted, due to the aforementioned bug, it persists a connection to the server. So the result is that after four template refreshes, I run out of server connections and my image no longer displays video.

Is there any way to prevent Meteor from refreshing this portion of the page but still keeping its reactivity? I tried putting the image into its own template and including the template from the larger template, but even the subtemplate gets rerendered.  I don't want to use {{#constant}} because the content in the template *should* be reactive. I just want to control when it gets rerendered, not when unrelated things change.

Any other ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use {{#isolate}} so code is only changed around the blocks you use reactivity in:

```
{{#isolate}}{{yourhelper}}{{/#isolate}}
```

Everything inside this `{{#isolate}}` block will be re-rendered but the rest would be considered separate. You can adjust it so your image is separate from the helpers causing you trouble.

You won't need to do this in the new Meteor-UI that's coming out soon :)

Comment: Aha!  That pointed me in the right direction. I didn't need to use isolate, I just needed to put the content that was changing in separate subtemplates so that they didn't cause the whole parent template to re-render.  That seems to have solved it, thanks!